# C# WPF datagrid ubicarme en determinada fila desde el código

Tags: c#, wpf

Hola amigos de este foro. Con un datagrid que tengo para capturar datos, cuando selecciono una fila con el ratón esta se colorea con el color correspondiente. Con el siguiente código, yo me ubico en determinada fila y celda de mi datagrid de trabajo:
`DataGridCellInfo cellInfo = new DataGridCellInfo(myGrd.Items[Fx], myGrd.Columns[Cx]);`
`myGrd.CurrentCell = cellInfo;`
Pero esto me coloca en determinada celda, y lo que necesito es ubicarme en la fila de tal forma que se vea resaltada con el color correspondiente. No he podido encontrar ningún ejemplo que me ayude con esto . Agradezco de antemano la ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias hacer esto

```
DataGrid.ScrollIntoView(DataGrid.Items[indiceFila]);
DataGrid.SelectedItem = DataGrid.Items[indiceFila];
```

La primera line hace que se mueva el scroll por si no esta visible y
la segunda hace que el focus se establesca en toda la fila

Espero que sea de ayuda o sea un camino para tu solucion.

Saludos

Comment: ¡¡¡EXCELENTE!!! Me funciona de maravillas. Muchas gracias.